# pdflatex - Error sometimes while converting latex to pdf

Tags: pdftex, ubuntu, linux

I am using `pdflatex` on `Ubuntu` in order to convert latex files to pdf files.

**I am converting the same file at randomly generated UUID paths that looks like that:**

```
/tmp/crawler-downloads/fc2071e4-63f7-4c12-b750-9ea21cd103fe/sample.tex
```

**Usage in python:**

```
process = Popen(['pdftex',
                     '--output-directory',
                     os.path.dirname(input_file_path),
                     '-interaction',
                     'nonstopmode',
                     input_file_path],
                    stdout=PIPE,
                    stderr=PIPE)
process.communicate(timeout=90)
```

**Which runs this line on command line:**

```
pdftex -interaction nonstopmode sample.tex
```

Sometimes the conversion is successful and sometimes it doesn't.

**At the generated log file I can see this error:**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.8.2)  2 AUG 2017 13:32
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**/tmp/crawler-downloads/3692ac8d-6a43-4164-ad30-49ef0c857c62/source.tex
(/tmp/crawler-downloads/3692ac8d-6a43-4164-ad30-49ef0c857c62/source.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty
Package: latexsym 1998/08/17 v2.2e Standard LaTeX package (lasy symbols)
\symlasy=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lasy' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/lasy/m/n --> U/lasy/b/n on input line 52.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2016/03/03 v2.15a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks15
\ex@=\dimen103
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count87
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 199.
\uproot@=\count88
\leftroot@=\count89
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 297.
\classnum@=\count90
\DOTSCASE@=\count91
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 394.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 397.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 518.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 630.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 631.
\macc@depth=\count92
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count93
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count94
\dspbrk@lvl=\count95
\tag@help=\toks16
\row@=\count96
\column@=\count97
\maxfields@=\count98
\andhelp@=\toks17
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks18
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks19
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2735.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2736.
)
\c@theorem=\count99

No file source.aux.
\openout1 = `source.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 33.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 33.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+lasy on input line 33.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd
File: ulasy.fd 1998/08/17 v2.2e LaTeX symbol font definitions
)

Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \atopwithdelims;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 62.

[1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2]
(/tmp/crawler-downloads/3692ac8d-6a43-4164-ad30-49ef0c857c62/source.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1194 strings out of 494953
 13827 string characters out of 6180978
 63239 words of memory out of 5000000
 4497 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 16702 words of font info for 69 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,6n,26p,517b,189s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr
/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/share
/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texli
ve/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx9.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmcsc10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dis
t/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/font
s/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type
1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/publi
c/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfo
nts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmr17.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr5.pf
b></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb></usr/
share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></usr/share/te
xlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb></usr/share/texlive/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-di
st/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fon
ts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type
1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/publ
ic/amsfonts/latxfont/lasy10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/publ
ic/amsfonts/latxfont/lcircle1.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/pu
blic/amsfonts/latxfont/line10.pfb>
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex: getcwd() failed (No such file or directory), path too 
long?
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

At the end of the log written:

```
    !pdfTeX error: pdflatex: getcwd() failed (No such file or directory), path too 
long?
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Is the problem really that is the path too long? Seems odd to me it can't handle that.

Is there any other solution for fixing it without changing the path of the files?

Comment: ive never seen that, but it's usually better to `cd input-dir; pdflatex localfilename` rather than `pdflatex --output-dir input-dir inputdir/localfilename` so you might try that?

Comment: That may be working but the problem i am running a multi threaded project and changing to each dircetory in order to convert a file is very problematic for me.

Comment: Try #!/bin/bash scripts... This will make things much easier